# ¿Como podría optimizar mas este código?

Tags: c#

me pidieron hacer un programa por consola que me muestre la cantidad de números perfectos que uno quiera ver, por ej el usuario ingresa 3, y que este me muestre los primeros 3 números perfectos, o si se ingresa el 4, que este me muestre los primeros 4 números perfectos!, Ya logre hacer un código que me permite hacer esto, pero cuando el usuario ingresa 5 o un numero mayor, los primeros 4 números perfectos me los imprime de manera instantánea y ya del 5to numero perfecto en adelante se demora una eternidad (el numero 5 se demora mas de 3 horas), entonces quería saber de que manera se podía optimizar mucho mejor este código para reducir su tiempo de búsqueda, gracias!!

```
            Console.WriteLine("ingrese N");
        int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int next = 1;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < N)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j < next; j++)
            {
                if (next % j == 0)
                    count = count + j;
            }

            if (count == next)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Numero perfecto :" + next);
                i++;
            }
            next++;
        }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: revise este artículo https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Número_perfecto donde explican caracteristicas que pueden ayudar a disminuir el número de operaciones de calculo a realizar, aunque no disminuye su complejidad

Comment: por otra parte el código que tiene solo puede resolver hasta el 5 número perfecto, (¿por qué?)

Comment: Se puede resolver mas alla del 5to numero perfecto, pero se demora mucho, por eso estoy buscando ayuda para poder optimizarlo mejor!!

Comment: Si, es posible resolver más alla del 5° número perfecto, pero lo que yo comente es que el código que tiene solo le va a funcionar hasta el 5°, de hay para a delante los va calcular de forma errada. En una pregunta anterior donde coloque código le escribi que no era necesario buscar los divisores hasta el número que se estaba evaluando y usted no tuvo presente eso, el quinto número perfecto es `33.550.336` por lo cual usted esta haciendo casi `16.000.000` de operaciones innecesarias

Comment: El problema que tienes es que estas recorriendo todos los valores desde 1 hasta 'next', siendo que no es necesario recorrerlos todos. Por ejemplo si next == 20, no tiene sentido recorrer del 11 en adelante. Otro punto es que si por ejemplo sabes que 2 es un divisor de 20, entonces puedes obtener otro divisor haciendo la operacion 20/2=10. Despues al llegar al 4, 20/4=5 y ya terminaste. Revisa este link para que entiendas el algoritmo paso a paso:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-divisors-natural-number-set-1/

Comment: Ah yaya, me acabo de dar cuenta que estoy evaluando números de mas, entonces en que parte del código podría colocar esa condición? es decir, que no me evaluee números más grande de la matidad del el número que se está evaluando?, gracias!

Comment: Jejeje la tarea es que ustedes lo optimicen y se dejen de copiar y pegar de Internet. Te pillamos po compadre. Ojo ya encontraron números perfectos impares. Atte. Profe Quezada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada, podemos optimizar la función para saber si un número es perfecto o no.
Sólo debemos contemplar aquellos números entre `2` y la raíz cuadrada del número en cuestión.

```
public static bool IsPerfect(long n)
{
    // Inicializamos la suma en 1, porque 1 siempre será un divisor de n
    long sum = 1;

    // Nos ahorramos el 1, empezamos el bucle en 2.
    // Para recorrer de 2 a la raíz de n, podemos hacer el cuadrado de i, es lo mismo.
    for (long i = 2; i * i <= n; i++)
    {

        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            // Sabemos que si n / i es división exacta, entonces
            // n / (n / i) también lo es.
            // Por lo que sumamos i y también (n / i)

            // Excepto en el caso que i * i sea n,
            // ya que entonces i es equivalente a (n / i)
            // y sólo debemos sumarlo una vez.
            if (i * i != n)
                sum += i + (n / i);
            else
                sum += i;
        }
    }

    // Finalmente, devolvemos si n es igual a la suma
    // Y evitamos el caso del 1, que no es perfecto, por definición.

    // Realmente, la comprobación del caso 1 no hace vale la pena ponerla justo
    // antes del bucle, ya que en el caso de 1 no se ejecuta ninguna iteración en el bucle
    return sum == n && n != 1;
}
```

Con esto, el algoritmo se optimiza bastante, ya que para cada número, se están haciendo menos comprobaciones. Hemos pasado de un coste n a un coste √n.

Siguiendo las características de los números perfectos, se desconoce que existan números perfectos impares (y si los hubiera, no se podrían representar con `long` en nuestros códigos). También se conoce que la fórmula para un número perfecto par es `2n-1(2n - 1)`. Así, podemos obviar muchos números.

El programa quedaría algo así.

```
int current = 1;
int found = 0;
while (found < max)
{
    long next = GetNext(current);
    if (IsPerfect(next))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Numero perfecto: {next}");
        ++found;
    }

    ++current;
}
```

Donde el método `GetNext` hace el cálculo de la fórmula descrita antes:

```
public static long GetNext(int current) =>
    (long)(Math.Pow(2, current - 1) * (Math.Pow(2, current) - 1));
```

En mi programa, `max` es la cantidad de números perfectos a encontrar (lo que para ti era `N`), `current` es la `n` de la fórmula y `found` la cantidad de números perfectos que se han encontrado.
Calcular los primeros 7 números perfectos es prácticamente inmediato

```
Numero perfecto: 6
Numero perfecto: 28
Numero perfecto: 496
Numero perfecto: 8128
Numero perfecto: 33550336
Numero perfecto: 8589869056
Numero perfecto: 137438691328
Elapsed 0.035 seconds
```

El octavo ya cuesta un poco de que salga.

```
Numero perfecto: 6
Numero perfecto: 28
Numero perfecto: 496
Numero perfecto: 8128
Numero perfecto: 33550336
Numero perfecto: 8589869056
Numero perfecto: 137438691328
Numero perfecto: 2305843008139952128
Elapsed 29.641 seconds
```

**Edit**
Leyendo un poco más, resulta que el número `n` de la fórmula `2n-1(2n - 1)` siempre debe ser un número primo.  Por lo tanto, podemos comprobar si el número que vamos a evaluar es primo, y si no, lo saltamos.

```
while (found < max)
{
    if (IsPrime(current))
    {
        long next = GetNext(current);

        if (IsPerfect(next))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Número perfecto: {next}");
            ++found;
        }
    }

    ++current;
}
```

Con el algoritmo optimizado de los números primos

```
public static bool IsPrime(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return false;
    if (n == 2) return true;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return false;

    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

De este modo, la búsqueda del 8º número perfecto se acelera considerablemente

```
Número perfecto: 6
Número perfecto: 28
Número perfecto: 496
Número perfecto: 8128
Número perfecto: 33550336
Número perfecto: 8589869056
Número perfecto: 137438691328
Número perfecto: 2305843008139952128
Elapsed 18.543 seconds
```

> ¿El noveno y décimo número se pueden calcular con este programa?

Lamentablemente, no. El noveno número ya sería del orden de `1037` y no sería representable con 64 bits (con ´ulong´). Habría que hacer una versión del mismo programa que pudiera trabajar con números enteros en diferentes *slots* en el *heap*, como los [`BigInteger`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1).

En fin, espero que te haya servido.

Comment: No entiendo porque no aprovechas el operador += en un caso del if mientras que en el otro sí

Comment: Por ninguna razón en particular.

Comment: Se me hace un poco dificil leer este codigo, asi que espero que me ayudes, cual se supone que es la clase main?? y los otros métodos están en clases separadas?, sorry por mi ignorancia pero estoy recien entrando a este campo de la programacion que tiene que ver con clases

Comment: [Aquí](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cgC5m2) tienes el ejemplo

Comment: Y el noveno numero, o el decimo, tambien se pueden calcular con este programa?

Comment: Te lo respondo con el edit en la misma respuesta.

Comment: En la formula `2^(n-1) * (2^n -1)`, `n` adicional a ser primo debe ser un primo de `Mersenne`